# Fundamental solution of product of linear operators in terms of their kernels

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Given that $K_a(x - y)$ and $K_b(x - y)$ are the kernels for the
> operators $(\Delta - aI)$ and $(\Delta - bI)$ on
> $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $0 < a < b$. Show that $(\Delta -
>  aI)(\Delta - bI)$ has a fundamental solution of the form $c_1K_a +
> c_2K_b$.
>
> Use the preceding to find a fundamental solution for $\Delta^2 -\Delta$, when $n = 3$.

Edit: Originally, it it stated that $K_a(x - y)$ is a kernel for $(\Delta - aI)^{-1}$, but I believe this should be $(\Delta - aI)$ instead.

Comment: What does $\Delta - > aI$ mean?

Comment: that's just a typo my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fundamental solution is one such that $(\Delta - aI)(\Delta - bI)f = 0$. We have
\begin{align}
        (\Delta - aI)(\Delta - bI)(c_1K_a + c_2K_b) &= c_1(\Delta - aI)(\Delta - bI)K_a + c_2(\Delta - aI)(\Delta - bI)K_b\\
        &= c_1(\Delta - aI)(\Delta - bI)K_a
    \end{align}
where in the last equality we used the fact that $(\Delta - bI)K_b = 0$ since $K_b$ is a kernel of $(\Delta - bI)$. On the other hand, we have
\begin{align}
        c_1(\Delta - aI)(\Delta - bI)K_a&= c_1 (\Delta^2 - \Delta bI - aI\Delta + aI bI)K_a\\
        &= c_1(\Delta^2 - \Delta a - b\Delta + bIaI)K_a\\
        &= c_1(\Delta(\Delta - aI) - bI(\Delta - aI))K_a\\
        &= c_1(\Delta(\Delta - aI) - bI(\Delta - aI))K_a\\
        &= c_1(\Delta - bI)(\Delta - aI)K_a\\
        &= 0
    \end{align}
where in the last equality we used the fact that $(\Delta - aI)K_b = 0$ since $K_a$ is a kernel of $(\Delta - aI)$.

In the case that $a = b = 1$, we have our solutions for $\Delta^2 - \Delta$ are of the form $c_1 K_1 + c_2K_2$.